# how to sum 2 record when using left join in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem when I use left join and group by running this code:

```
select   a.[fromAccCode] 
    ,a.[CenterCode]    
  , CASE WHEN b.CFCUSTYP = 0 THEN 'm' ELSE 'n' END AS person
 ,sum(a.[value]) 'sumValue'
  from  [dbo].[tmp_dep_ex] a left join [dbo].[5_CBCIF] b
  on a.[CFCIFNO]=b.[CFCIFNO]
  group by  a.[CenterCode] 
  ,a.[fromAccCode]
  ,b.CFCUSTYP
  order by 
  a.[CenterCode] 
  ,a.[fromAccCode]
  ,b.CFCUSTYP
```

The result is:

### Result is

```
fromAccCode | CenterCode | person | sumValue

201443      | 3/2/0160   | m      | 1707632873

201443      | 3/2/0160   | n      | 8723822181

201443      | 3/2/0160   | m      | 173260000
```

How to change this result to:

```
fromAccCode | CenterCode | person | sumValue

201443      | 3/2/0160   | m      | 1880892873

201443      | 3/2/0160   | n      | 8723822181
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Larnu It's a good advice but not related to question

Comment: @AlexYu it really is. The OP used the alias `a` for `tmp_dep_ex` and `b` for `[5_CBCIF]`. Those are not good aliases for their objects. Just because it's not answering the question they asked (which is why it's a comment), doesn't mean it's not related to their question. Good use of Aliasing, White space, Line breaks, etc, all make for far better SQL. Aaron Bertrand is an expert in SQL, and his "Bad habits" article are a great resource for those old and new to the language.

Comment: @Larnu I'm all for good alias names but the OP problem  he does `GROUP BY` on wrong set of fields

Comment: I know that @AlexYu, again, why I've made the above a comment; it's not an answer however, I'm helping the OP improve their SQL none-the-less. You'll find a lot of users post helpful articles like I have in the comments; a very common one you see is another by Bertrand on using "Old Style joins" (the ANSI-89 syntax). They don't "answer" the question, but they are all being posted to help the OP, and others, improve their knowledge of the language and to help them advance in the area. You'll probably see this regularly as you use the site more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `CASE WHEN b.CFCUSTYP = 0 THEN 'm' ELSE 'n' END` in group by clause

```
select   a.[fromAccCode] 
    ,a.[CenterCode]    
  , CASE WHEN b.CFCUSTYP = 0 THEN 'm' ELSE 'n' END AS person
 ,sum(a.[value]) 'sumValue'
  from  [dbo].[tmp_dep_ex] a left join [dbo].[5_CBCIF] b
  on a.[CFCIFNO]=b.[CFCIFNO]
  group by  a.[CenterCode] 
  ,a.[fromAccCode]
  ,CASE WHEN b.CFCUSTYP = 0 THEN 'm' ELSE 'n' END
  order by 
  a.[CenterCode] 
  ,a.[fromAccCode]
```